# Is there any alternative for Cloudera Manager? (CDH)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

As Cloudera official blog said, there is no free version of CDH from 6.3.3, they would make the Cloudera Manager to open source, but not yet.

Is there any other project like Cloudera Manager? which can manage Hadoop components by Web UI, especially belongs to Apache projects.

BTW, HDP also is not available for new version.

Answer (score -2):

I am using the `Cloudera Virtual Machine`

You can still download a `docker image` of the `QuickstartVM`

[DockerQuickstartVM](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart)

or you can try this link too

[cloudera-quickstart-vm-virtualbox](https://downloads.cloudera.com/demo_vm/virtualbox/cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0-virtualbox.zip)

Answer (score -2):

There is Arendata:
https://store.arenadata.io/index_en.html (vendor is Russian, but they have english versions on the page)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26703610)

Comment: Ammended my response.